# How to modify data in Observable in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working on learning Angular 2 and Typescript. I am building a simple web application that grabs data from a WEB API and displays it in a list. Then once the user clicks an item in the list, they are taken to a details page.

I have a service that I created to make the API call that does the following:

```
   GetData() { 
         let data = this.http.get('http://server.name/api/GetData')
                  .map((res) => res.json());
         return data; 
   }
```

Then in a component, I subscribe to the data like this:

```
      this.myService.GetData()
      .subscribe((myService) => this.items = myService);
```

When the http.get returns, I would like to do some processing on the JSON objects before I return from the GetData() method. For example, add a new property called ID. Essentially something like the pseudo code below:

```
 for each(item in data) { 
     item.ID = newID(); //method for creating IDs 
 }
```

1. Is this something that can be done?
2. If yes, is it something that SHOULD be done, or is there a better way to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Thanks

Comment: This is not `angularjs`. There's already one `map`, what does stop you from adding an another one? The operator exists exactly for that.

Comment: Sorry, that was the tag suggested by Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do the processing in your GetData's code, within the `map`:

```
// For RxJS v5 
    this.http
      .get('http://server.name/api/GetData')
      .map(result => {
         const items = <any[]>result.json(); // could be SomeItem[] instead of any[]
         items.forEach(item => item.ID = ...);
         return items;
      });

// For RxJS v6 
    this.http
     .get('http://server.name/api/GetData')
     .pipe(map(result => {
        const items = <any[]>result.json(); // could be SomeItem[] instead of any[]
        items.forEach(item => item.ID = ...);
        return items;
      }));
```

Then when you receive the object in your subscribe, the items should have the IDs assigned.

Here's the reference to the RxJs Observable's documentation: http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-map

Answer (score 2):

the idea is to :

- get the result
- map the result to get the json only
- as your json is an array, produce an Observable for each data, then change its id and sent the data back
- gather them back in an array

the mergeMap (replaced flatMap in rxjs 5.5+) operator is used because an Observable operator always sends back an Observable, but since we create an Observable inside the result itself, it produces an Observable>, mergeMap removes an Observable layer. Hope this helps

```
GetData():Observable<WhateverWithIDInside[]> { 
  let data = this.http.get('http://server.name/api/GetData')
    .map(res => res.json())
    .mergeMap(dataArr =>
      Observable.from(dataArr)
        .map(data => {
          data.ID = newID();
          return data;
        })
        .toArray()
   );
}
```

Comment: I prefer this version because you don't need to subscribe to your observable so you could use the async pipe in Angular2